# Swift: How to get string values of days, months and year from a date picker?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar, uidatepicker

i want to get the separate Strings values of day,Month,year from a date picker. and assign these three values to a 3 variables. I have done upto this:

```
@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = GlobalConfiguration.getDatePickerFormat()
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.datePicker.date)
    self.delegate?.datePickerDidSelect(formattedDate)
    }
```

this is my few codes and i can set the date text as a string to the button title.Now i want days,month and year separately. How can i do this..??

Comment: Please write the output. i.e the string you are getting from date formatter.

Comment: what type output you expect, can you show some example

Comment: yes of course. I have to pass each day,month and year as a parameter. so i want to extract individual components

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do that, depends if you want to see the number of the current month or his name:

- Use [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar)
- Use [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter)

With [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar):

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: self.datePicker.date))
if let day = components.day, let month = components.month, let year = components.year {
    let dayString = String(day)
    let monthString = String(month)
    let yearString = String(year)
}
```

With [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let year: String = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date))
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
let month: String = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date))
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let day: String = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date))
```

With [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter) you have more choice of formatting because your manage the output format

Comment: Replace date by the date of your picker

Comment: @Sam How this code work in Swift 2.x is you who told you are working with Swift 2  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040875/swifthow-to-get-string-values-of-days-months-and-year-from-date-picker#comment75108106_44041022

Comment: And 'components.day' is an optional variable, it's better to check before unboxing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSDateComponents` for that.

```
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: self.datePicker.date)
let year = String(dateComponents.year)
let month = String(dateComponents.month)
let day = String(dateComponents.day)
```

Comment: @Sam I know and that's why I added code in Swift 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
   if let date = self.datePicker.date {
        let components = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year],from:date)
        if let day = components.day, let month = components.month, let year = components.year {
            let dayString = "\(day)"
            let monthString = "\(month)"
            let yearString = "\(year)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: These are not strings.