# How can I save CoreData object on the same day?

Tags: swift, core-data

is there a way to save multiple CoreData objects on the same day?

```
let newitem = Record(context: viewContext)
newitem.date = Date()
newitem.totaltime = item.totaltime
```

and on the same Date() in the next time

```
totaltime += 200
```

I used this, but it doesn't work

```
if !ro.filter({$0.date == Date()}).isEmpty{
}else{
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do so we can get a better idea?

Comment: `Date()` contains more precise information than just day/month/year - up to miliseconds if I’m not mistaken. So when you filter by `Date()` its an entirely different object (representing a different point in time) than the one you had when saving the record. You need to extract only the relevanant components.

Comment: I closed this with two links, one for using NSPredicate and one for using for instance filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, in the `.filter{}` method, filtering by just `Date()` won't do.

See the example below,

```
let now = Date()
var delayedDate: Date!

// Causing a delay of 1 second
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    delayedDate = Date() // Date after one second
    print("Date now:", now, ", Delayed date:", delayedDate!) // Printing the dates. See that they are not equal
    print(now == delayedDate) // Checking if the dates are equal will result in false
}
```

This will result in the following

[image]

What this means that the date object you are comparing with the ones from CoreData is not equal. You can say that you are trying to equate **COMPLETELY different objects**.

So what you can do is, use a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356392/how-to-get-day-and-month-from-date-type-swift-4) link to break a `Date()` object into components such as `date`, `hour`, `minute`, etc. and then compare the `date` component with the ones from CoreData. Note that the component conversion needs to be done for the CoreData Dates as well