# How do I read the year of an MPMediaItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

The documentation here shows only the variable `releaseDate`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem

This variable is almost always empty in the case of my own music library. But there is a separate field, both in the metadata of mp3/m4a files and also in the MediaLibrary.sqlitedb, a column called `year` in the table `item_extra`, which contains only the year itself and not the full release date. How do I read this field through Swift on iOS?

Comment: You could extract the year from the `releaseDate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040875/

Comment: @koen that's a separate field, in the example of my own music library, almost all files have a year, but no releaseDate.
I will edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to read it this way:

```
if let itemYearNumber = item.value(forProperty: "year") as? NSNumber {
    return itemYearNumber.intValue == yearInt
}
```

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4895053/341994 (translated).